# How to get the remainder of multiple array values?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating something fun for myself just to improve my knowledge and im currently stuck at this problem, where I need to get the remainder of 2 array values.

It's gonna be hard to explain with words, so I'll try my best to write it out. The code below will display 20 lines with numbers, for example, the first numbers are gonna be 1441 and 1468, what I need is to subtract the first number and the second number to get the first numbers results/remainder, which is gonna be 1441-1468, which results to -27, and then the 2nd number is gonna subtract the number 3rd number in the array, which comes after 1468.

Simpler explanation:
1441 - this is the first number, that subtracts the number below
1468 - this is the number, that gets subtracted and as a result you get the sum. Then this number subtracts the number below, which is 1445, and so forth.
1445.

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function getStats() {
    let res = await axios.get(`https://api.faceit.com/stats/api/v1/stats/time/users/57c80380-a00f-47ff-996f-8e541156e3c0/games/csgo?size=20`);
    let data = res.data;
    return data;
}

getStats()
.then(stats => {
    let eloArr = [];
    for (let i=0; i < stats.length; i++) {
        eloArr.push(stats[i].elo);
        console.log(eloArr[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: You should take a look at `array.reduce` method to achieve what you want.

Comment: You didn’t explain what you wanted to do with the results/remainders. Are you going to store them? Display them or what?

Comment: `1441 - 1468 - 1445 ...` is this what you want to do? Please explain with an example

Comment: With 1441, 1468, 1445... Do you intend to do 1441 - 1468 = -27, then -27 - 1445 = -1472... Or 1441 - 1468 = -27 then 1468 - 1445 = 23...?

Comment: I drew a quick drawing to maybe help explain better https://i.imgur.com/VzmzVBx.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of trying to figure this problem out, I settled on the easiest solution. It's not by far the best solution, but works for what I need.

This is what I wanted to get as a final result - https://repl.it/repls/HelpfulNoxiousDigits

Answer (score 1):

This is what is understand from your question and try to solve your issue.

```js
const arr = [1441,1468,1445,1512,1621,1000];

let finalAnswer = [];


for(let i = 1;i<arr.length;i++)
{
  finalAnswer.push(arr[i-1] - arr[i]);
}

console.log(finalAnswer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure what you want as a final result. Maybe this would work for you.

```
getStats()
.then(stats => {
    let eloArr = [stats[0].elo];
    console.log(eloArr[0]);
    let total = stats[0].elo;
    for (let i = 1; i < stats.length; i++) {
        eloArr.push(stats[i].elo);
        console.log(stats[i].elo);
        total -= stats[i].elo;
    }
    console.log(total);
});
```